# How to pass string parameter to DELETE WebAPI endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

When creating a new ASP.net WebAPi Rest controller,  visual studio adds a DELETE action like this

```
// DELETE: api/foo/5
public void Delete(int id)
{
}
```

And I can successfully call that endpoint

But the 'id' in my system are string hashes so I need to pass the 'id' as a string not an int  e.g

```
// DELETE: api/foo/58c75babbf61cda99c84af8b
public void Delete(string id)
{
}
```

But when I change this, the DELETE action no longer is called and I get the error `"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI "`

Any ideas why? and how do get around this?

Comment: this is a route config issue. show how you configured routes. provide [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the route template yourself, and in it, specify that id is a guid:

```
[HttpDelete, Route("api/foo/{id}")]
public void Delete(string id)
{
}
```

Comment: But the Id is not a guid.  It's just a string.

Comment: OK, I see. Sorry for the misunderstanding, see my edited answer.

Comment: Your edit doesn't work either, but  what does work is if the attribute looks like this  [HttpDelete, Route("api/foo/{id}")]

Comment: I checked the documentation. Unfortunately alpha really means 'alpha' and not 'alphanumberic', so numbers are out... But I guess we could still use the regex route constraint like this `{id:regex(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$)}`. This should match any number of alphanumeric character. But if it works just by specifying the type, I guess that's the best solution :) Thanks for the educational question and sharing the answer.